# Add another list entry to object elements list Java JPA @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, one-to-many

As topic suggests, I have this list within my object that I need to add another entry to.

The app is a rest API backend that will receive objects, and within the object I have lists. In this list , I need to add another entry. I seem to overwrite my old entries attributes'.

Can you help me figure out what I gotta change?

**The list**

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    private Date created;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    private Date updated;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myList")
    private List<myItem> items;
```

**The items within list**

```
@Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    String itemId;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    private Date created;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    private Date updated;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "list_id")
    private myList myList;
```

**The service/logic**

```
public ResponseEntity<myList> addItem(myList myList) {
        myList oldList = myListRepository.findById(myList.getId()).orElse(null);

        if (oldList != null && myList != null && myList.getItems() != null && myList.getItems().size() > 0) {
            List<myItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

            for (myItem item : myList.getItems()) {
                item.setCreated(new Date());
                item.setUpdated(new Date());
                items.add(item);
            }
            syncStuff(items);

            for (myItem item : oldList.getItems()) {
                item.setUpdated(new Date());
                items.add(item);
            }

            for (myItem item : items) {
                myItemRepository.saveAndFlush(item);
            }

            myList.getItems().addAll(items);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(myListRepository.saveAndFlush(myList), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: What is in the myList.getItems() that you would want to set the created/updated dates on it? And why are you touching all items in the oldList.getItems() list? If this is REST api, chances are you are sending back the full myList back and forth, which already includes the old myItem entries.- your ArrayList is going to have duplicates that you iterate and call myItemRepository.saveAndFlush over, that is likely the source of your issues. What to do though depends on what you actually want to happen. Pick the version you actually want to keep and only call save on it.

Comment: Thanks did just that!

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accept it ;) Thanks!